# I am getting syntax error in dynamic cretated SQL statement,near LIKE operator

Tags: c#, sql, asmx

> I am trying to write dynamic SQL statement, but i am getting exception syntax error,near LIKE operator where i used down in SQL statement 
>   webmethod.asmx.cs

```
[WebMethod]
                    public void leavesRequest_data_to_hr()
                    {
                        List<leavesrecord> record = new List<leavesrecord>();
                        string Todaydate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                        string status = "Pending";
                        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source = AMARNATHB; Initial Catalog = sample; Integrated Security = True");
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select leaverequest.id,leaverequest.emp_id,leaverequest.date_inserted,leavesSignup.name,leaverequest.leaves_form,leaverequest.leaves_upto,leaverequest.leave_type,leaverequest.description,leaverequest.no_of_leaves from leaverequest inner join leavesSignup on leaverequest.emp_id = leavesSignup.emp_id where leaverequest.date_inserted like '%'"+Todaydate+"'%' and leaverequest.status='" + status + "'", connection);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        connection.Open();
                        SqlDataReader idr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        while (idr.Read())
                        {
                        }
        }
```

Comment: You should really look into using parameters instead of concatenating your variables. It would prevent problems like '%'"+Todaydate+"'%' that should instead be '%"+Todaydate+"%'  depends also if date_inserted is a string.

Comment: Why would you use LIKE with a date qualifier?  Is `2020-02-11` "like" `2020-02-12`? are they more alike than say, `2020-12-02`?  Use SQL parameters.  *This is the way*

Comment: like is for strings/varchar etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple issues with this logic:

```
" . . . leaverequest.date_inserted like '%'" + Todaydate + "'%' . . .
```

First, what it produces is:

```
leaverequest.date_inserted like '%'<some date value here>'%'
```

There are extra meaningless single quotes which are causing the syntax error.

More important than the syntax error are these two problems:

- You are (presumably) treating a date column as if it were a string.  Agghhh!  `like` is for strings not dates.
- You are passing in a value that munges your query string.  This can make the code prone to SQL injection.  It can make the code subject to hard-to-debug errors.

How about letting the database do the work?

```
" . . . convert(date, leaverequest.date_inserted) = convert(date, getdate()) . . .
```

I am assuming that you are using SQL Server.  But similar constructs exist in all databases.

And, all other parameter values should be passed in as *parameters*, not by munging the query string.